# How do I generate an SSHFP record from a remote ssh server (like a router)?

Tags: ssh, dnssec

How do I generate an SSHFP DNS records for a server like a router that does not give you direct access to their keys in a format that `ssh-keygen -r machine` understands?

The `ssh-keygen -r machine` reads private keys on the local machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate an SSHFP record for a remote ssh server, run the following tool:

```
Little-Net:~ minfrin$ ssh-keyscan -D machine.example.com
; machine.example.com:22 SSH-2.0-ROSSSH
; machine.example.com:22 SSH-2.0-ROSSSH
machine.example.com IN SSHFP 1 1 d9d29098100fe5ebbb7d912a5b0d8cc13a32f557
machine.example.com IN SSHFP 1 2 61ac073f5cdfd6957f61d0af26450717d4eb59c2b02a6798410003d0dada7dcf
; machine.example.com:22 SSH-2.0-ROSSSH
```

From ssh-keyscan man page:

```
 -D      Print keys found as SSHFP DNS records.  The default is to print keys in a format usable as a ssh(1) known_hosts file.
```

Comment: From `ssh-keyscan` man page: `-D      Print keys found as SSHFP DNS records.  The default is to print keys in a format usable as a ssh(1) known_hosts file.`